# Is it possible to have a MassTransit Saga react to events that come from more that one bus (multibus)?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, masstransit, saga

I have a MassTransit Saga that works great with events, activites etc. in the context of the bus (Azure Service Bus) for which saga has been configured.

During one of the states I need to send a message to a different bus (another Azure Service Bus). That works fine using MultiBus. But, during next step I would like to receive a topic message from that separate bus and react to it.

Is that supported atm in MassTransit Saga?

Comment: Have you gone through this [saga guidance](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/guidance.html)

Comment: not yet, but looks interesting. thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the same saga on multiple bus instances using the same saga repository. You can add the repository separately with the `AddSagaRepository<T>` method, to avoid having to configure it twice.

You would need to call `AddSagaStateMachine` within each `AddMassTransit` block.

Comment: Thanks so much for such a quick reply!